# how many chaincodes are required for 3 organizations hyperledger network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I want to build a hyperledger fabric network for 3 organizations, and I want to develop chaincode for the network. So how many chaincodes I have develop to 3 organization network. Is it like between org1 and org2 one chaincode, and org2 and org3 one chaincode. please help me through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they share the channel and business logic, only one. From then, as much as you need or want.

Comment: So if three organization are in one channel then only one chaincode is enough? So in my case org1 and org2 have link and org2 and org3 have link. But it org1 and org3 does not have link. Then i need to create two channels and two chaincode right? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand you well. The chaincode is a smart  contract, your program, software. You share the chaincode (the source code itself or packaged) with the other organizations that share the channel and business logic. The administrators of each organization install the chaincode on their peers. Then, one administrator (any of them if there are no instantiation polices) instantiate the code on the channel.